# how to apply url validator in asp textbox feild

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net & my client needs to fill the url in text box & without proper url the form should not be submitted. Can anybody know how to apply url validator in textbox fields in asp.net.
Please let me know about it thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtUrl" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Use a regular expression:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegExUrl" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must be in a website format" ControlToValidate="TxtUrl" ValidationExpression="(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If the field is required before submission, use this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ReqUrl" ControlToValidate="TxtUrl" ErrorMessage="Required" />
```

---

Alternatively, you can use an HTML5 input with the type of url ([w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_url)):

```
<input type="url">
```

Comment: Thank you i got it